# Converting php regex to javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to convert following regex:

```
^(?:\d{12}|\d{9}|(?i:YHZ)?\d{6}|(?i:YHZ)?\d{8})$
```

into javascript but facing issues for escaping or handling "(?"

I tried verifying on `https://regex101.com/#javascript` but unable to handle it can anyone please share what needs to fix in the above regex so it can work in javascript

Comment: what does this regex do?

Comment: it validates for following cases
a.  yhz+6numeric  (not case sensitive for the yhz)
b. yhz+8numeric  (not case sensitive for the yhz)
c. 6numeric
d. 8numeric
e. 9 numeric
f. 12 numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support partial case insensitive patterns. So `(?:i` is invalid in JS.

Use `i` flag to make the regex in-case-sensitive

```
/^(?:\d{12}|\d{9}|(YHZ)?\d{6}|(YHZ)?\d{8})$/i
```

[**Regex 101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aA6xO8/1)

---

From Comments:

> ```
> it validates for following cases
>
> a.    yhz+6numeric (not case sensitive for the yhz)
> b.    yhz+8numeric (not case sensitive for the yhz)
> c.    6numeric
> d.    8numeric
> e.    9numeric
> f.    12numeric
> ```

The regex can be rewritten as

```
/^((yhz)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)$/i
```

Test this regex on [**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aA6xO8/2)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="((yhz|YHZ)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)" />

<br />
<br />it validates for following cases

<ul>
  <li>yhz + 6numeric</li>
  <li>yhz + 8numeric</li>
  <li>6 numeric</li>
  <li>8 numeric</li>
  <li>9 numeric</li>
  <li>12 numeric</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Regex Visual]

If you don't want any capture group, use `(?:` at the beginning of group.

```
/^(?:(?:yhz)?[0-9]{6}(?:[0-9]{2})?|(?:[0-9]{6})(?:(?:[0-9]{2,3})|(?:[0-9]{6}))?)$/i
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aA6xO8/3)

[image: Regex Visualization]

Comment: I used the code /^((yhz)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)$/i but i have to put the following into DHC where i have to add this regex to a key "format_validation_regex": "/^((yhz)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)$/i";, but now it gives error message for anything i enter

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="((yhz|YHZ)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)" />

<br />
<br />it validates for following cases

<ul>
  <li>yhz + 6numeric</li>
  <li>yhz + 8numeric</li>
  <li>6 numeric</li>
  <li>8 numeric</li>
  <li>9 numeric</li>
  <li>12 numeric</li>
</ul>
```

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="((yhz|YHZ)?[0-9]{6}([0-9]{2})?|([0-9]{6})(([0-9]{2,3})|([0-9]{6}))?)" />

<br />
<br />it validates for following cases

<ul>
  <li>yhz + 6numeric</li>
  <li>yhz + 8numeric</li>
  <li>6 numeric</li>
  <li>8 numeric</li>
  <li>9 numeric</li>
  <li>12 numeric</li>
</ul>
```